# move content from one hidden div to another displayed div

Tags: jquery

how do i move content from one hidden div to another displayed div using jquery?

say i have div1 with display style is none and another div "div2" with display style block.

how do I move the content from div1 to div2 and clear div1?

Comment: Where are you moving the content to specifically? Prepended or appended, in a specific target, etc.?

Comment: I found a good answer related to this question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792352/how-do-you-move-html-from-one-div-to-another-with-jquery-without-breaking-javasc

Answer (score 22):

`.contents()` may be what you need:

```
$('#div1').contents().appendTo('#div2')
```

Take note that it will *move* (not copy) the inner elements from one div to the other.

Comment: Not sure you need the surrounding $() - you can make it `$('#div1').contents().appendTo('#div2');`

Comment: @jbyrd that's quite possible... maybe someone can do a jsfiddle. Or feel free to just edit my post if you're pretty sure that works

Comment: Yes, I just confirmed it works without the extra $().

Answer (score 11):

Why not just show the hidden div and hide the displayed one?

But to answer your question.

```
 $('#div2').html($('#div1').html());
$('#div1').html('');
```

Comment: @ronald-yoh - Are you including jQuery in the page? when your question is tagged with jquery, there is an assumption you're using it.

Comment: Small thing, but for the second line, use `.empty()` - more semantically explicit (and slightly faster).

Answer (score 0):

```
$( $('#div1').html() ).appendTo('#div2')
```

Comment: error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: fixed. if you are getting that runtime error, chances are it's not our code and it's something else on your end.

Answer (score 0):

First you'd need to get the HTML from DIV1, and then set the HTML in DIV2.

Use the get/set operations available on the [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html1) selector.

Like this:

```
var div1Html = $('#div1').html();
$('#div2').html(div1Html);
```

Comment: sounds like something else on your page. i created a simple page with nothing but two div's and the above code works fine (as does everyone else's similar answers)

Comment: please note the form is on MVC framework.. it might behave differently.. thanks

Comment: javascript/jquery deals with html and the DOM only (client-side), it has no bearing on what web server technology (web forms, mvc)