# Token Input - Moving from one div to other

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

As per the requirement i want to move the token input from one div to another div.

I am able to move the token input data from one div to other but the token input feature is not working in other div.

Below is the code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tokeninput.js" ></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="token-input.css"  rel="stylesheet"></link>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                initialize();
        });
        function initialize() {
            $("#demo-input").tokenInput([
                {id: 7, name: "Ruby"},
                {id: 11, name: "Python"},
                {id: 13, name: "JavaScript"},
                {id: 17, name: "ActionScript"},
                {id: 19, name: "Scheme"},
                {id: 23, name: "Lisp"},
                {id: 29, name: "C#"},
                {id: 31, name: "Fortran"},
                {id: 37, name: "Visual Basic"},
                {id: 41, name: "C"},
                {id: 43, name: "C++"},
                {id: 47, name: "Java"}
            ]);
        }
        function change() {
            if( $(".div2").html().trim().length == 0 ) {
                $(".div2").html( $(".div1").html() );
                $(".div1").html('');
            } else {
                $(".div1").html( $(".div2").html() );
                $(".div2").html('');
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div1" style="border:1px solid red">
        <input type="text" id="demo-input" name="blah" />
    </div>

    <input type="button" onclick="change()"  value="ClicktoMove" />
    <div class="div2"  style="border:1px solid yellow">

    </div>
</body>
```

Can any one help on this...

Comment: Do you need to state of the token input to be maintained? If not, I image reinitialising would be the best move.

Comment: @Chris reinitialising will not work as plugin duplicate the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use .html(), the children will lose the events binded to it.

If you are copying just one element from one place to other than you can use `.clone(true)`

If you are moving multiple elements, like in your case, than you need to use `element.contents()`

For more details, read [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2792416/569751).

Here is the [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/jGq7L/2/).

Changes to your code:

```
function change() {
    if($.trim($(".div2").html()).length === 0 ) {
        $(".div2").html($(".div1").contents());
        $(".div1").html('');
    }
    else
    {
        $(".div1").html( $(".div2").contents() );
        $(".div2").html('');
    }
}
```